# PHP Array building with foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to build an array that I can output using JSON. For whatever reason, it will only add one element to the array, even if there are multiple email addresses that come back with the object. I know this because the loop executes the correct amount of times. However the new values are not added to the array. I tried array_push but it mal forms the array and jQuery wont process it correctly.

```
        $load_model = $this->loadModel("LoadModel");
        $x = $load_model->updateLoad($LoadRate, $carrID, $comment, $temp, $loadStatus, $contactID, $load_id);
            if($x==true){
                $arr=array();
                foreach($load_model->loadEmailAddresses($load_id) as $val){
                   $arr['Email']= $val->Email;
                   $arr['ContactId']= $val->ContactId;
                }
                echo json_encode($arr);
            }
```

any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 4):

You are setting the same element over and over in the loop. Every time it loops it will set `$arr['Email']` and `$arr['ContactId']`. In the end you'll only ever get the last value that went through the loop. You'll need to create an array for the email and contact id, then add that array to `$arr`.

```
$load_model = $this->loadModel("LoadModel");
$x = $load_model->updateLoad($LoadRate, $carrID, $comment, $temp, $loadStatus, $contactID, $load_id);
    if($x==true){
        $arr=array();
        foreach($load_model->loadEmailAddresses($load_id) as $val){
           $arr[] = array('Email' => $val->Email, 'ContactId' => $val->ContactId);
        }
        echo json_encode($arr);
    }
```

Comment: Ah dhur, dunno how I missed that. Now I have a multidimensional array passed to the Jquery. Do I just iterate over the returned data?

Comment: Yup, you'll have to handle that data in jQuery knowing it could be any number of records.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the lines in your foreach loop to

```
$arr[] = array(
    'Email'=>$val->Email,
    'ContactId'=>$val->ContactId,
);
```

Your array should grow properly at this point.